# Lost saved games and profiles on Xbox 360 after getting on Xbox live

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, xbox-network

I was playing Skyrim and screen froze.  I turned it off and when I turned it back on all my saved games and game profiles were gone and only got the Xbox live home page.  There was no history of any of the games my family had been playing or their profiles.  I spent about an hour with support and am still waiting for an answer.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It almost sounds as though your system experienced a system halt and hard drive failure, Check the system settings under memory for a hard drive, if one shows up try creating a profile and save to it, if it accepts the save then I'm wrong. Otherwise your drive went bad, request a new one from microsoft if it is under warranty.